# how can i convert java code to python for-loop

Tags: java, python

i don't have idea how to convert java code to python code.

```
for(int i=0; i<16; i++ ){
   tmp[i]= (float) tmp[i] + Math.sqrt((Math.pow((a[0][i] - b[0]),2))); }
```

here is java code

```
for i in range(0,16):
   tmp[i] = 0 # initialization temp
   tmp[i] =  dist_tmp[i] + ((a[0][i] - a[0])**2)**0.5
```

my attempt

Comment: What is `tmp` initialized to in the Java code before your `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

for i in range(16):
    tmp[i] = 0
    tmp[i] = float(tmp[i]) + math.sqrt(math.pow(a[0][i] - b[0], 2))
```

Comment: `tmp[i] = 0` - here you use variable `i` outside of loop

Comment: Good answers *explain* as well as provide code. Consider updating your answer to include an explanation about how this code works and why it is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct in general and needs minimal corrections. You could use following code:

```
tmp = [0]*16 # init tmp as a list containing 16 zero elements if needed
for i in range(16):
    tmp[i] = dist_tmp[i] + ((a[0][i] - b[0])**2)**0.5
```